# How can I avoide Forced unwarapping in this?

Tags: swift, forced-unwrapping

How can I avoid forced unwrapping in below code?

```
 self.array = self.array.sorted(by: { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ($0?.event?.dateRecorded)!) > Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ($1?.event?.dateRecorded)!) })
```

Comment: Is that the real code? Why is `$0` optional? Why `$0?.event` but `$1?.bgEvent` ?

Comment: yes it is optional., it is a real code

Comment: Is conversion from timestamp(?) to `Date` is really necessary for comparison?

Comment: @MartinR, `array: [T?]`

Comment: @user28434: You are right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nil-coalescing to replace a `nil` timestamp with some default value,
e.g. a timestamp far far in the past:

```
let past = -TimeInterval.greatestFiniteMagnitude
self.array.sort(by: { 
     $0.event?.dateRecorded ?? past > $1.event?.dateRecorded ?? past
})
```

As mentioned above, there is no need to compare the timestamps
to `Date` values, the numeric timestamps can be compared directly.

Comment: If result of sorting of `array` is assigned back to original variable, it would be easier to just use [`sort`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort). IIRC it's more memory efficient.